# Vulkan on Android with Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, vulkan

There is a [Vulkan Graphics API](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/) as part of the Android [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/) which Visual Studio includes if you follow the instructions [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/13/android-ndk-r15c-support-goes-in-box-in-visual-studio-2017-version-15-6-preview/). You can find the install location of this NDK by going to Tools > Options > Cross Platform > C++ > Android. So I went to that location with windows file explorer and did a search for "vulkan" and sure enough there are Vulkan header files and folders and such. I just don't know what the proper files I need to reference are and how to reference them within Visual Studio.

Is it possible to develop a Vulkan Android app using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017? If so, how would I reference the Vulkan API from my native Android project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible to build native Vulkan applications using Visual Studio 2017.

To use Vulkan you only need to include the `vulkan.h` header file. That header will automatically include all other headers required for using Vulkan depending on your target platform.

Note that older android platform versions (23 and lower) don't include the vulkan.so library, so if you target these you'd need to dynamically load the Vulkan function pointers, even for non-extension functionality.

Comment: If you need a reference, you can take a look at my C++ Vulkan samples at https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan

I have moved to Android Studio for my Android builds, but I can imagine that it is possible to convert the Android part to build with VS2017.

Comment: But which vulkan.h header file do I need to include? There's one in `..\android-ndk-r15c\platforms\android-x\arch-x\usr\include\vulkan`, one in `..\android-ndk-r15c\sysroot\usr\include\vulkan` and one in `..\android-ndk-r15c\sources\third_party\vulkan\src\include\vulkan`. And how do I add the vulkan.so library as a dependence to my project? I found a "libvulkan.so" file in `..\android-ndk-r15c\platforms\android-x\arch-x\usr\lib`, is that what you're referencing?

Comment: Oh looks like Visual Studio handled that for me. I just updated the target API level and looks like I can now use the Vulkan library.

Answer (score 0):

On WINDOWS, after the update, Android Studio stopped working.

I downloaded vulkan-1.dll from [here](https://www.dll-files.com/vulkan-1.dll.html).
Then rename the file to **vulkan-1.dll** and place it in

> C:\Android\SDK\emulator\lib64

This was the only solution (after multiple attempts) for me.